# Generate random numbers distributed by Zipf

Tags: math, random, probability

The [Zipf probability distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Zipf%27s_law) is often used to model file size distribution or item access distributions on items in P2P systems. e.g. ["Web Caching and Zip like Distribution Evidence and Implications"](http://www.nslij-genetics.org/wli/zipf/breslau99.pdf), but neither [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/random/index.html) or the [GSL (Gnu Scientific Library)](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-Number-Distributions.html) provide an implementation to generate random numbers using this distribution. I have not found a (trustworthy) implementation using the common search engines.

*How can random numbers that are distributed according to the Zipf distribution by using a U(0,1) random generator, e.g. the [Mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister)?*

Comment: A recent paper (Maurizio Naldi, 2015) proposes an approximation algorithm with a parameter that trades off time and accuracy. For a reasonable range of alpha (0 <= alpha <= 2) the error never exceeds 0.1%. See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.01480.pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[zipfR](http://zipfr.r-forge.r-project.org/) is a free and open source library implemented with R. [VGAM](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~yee/VGAM/) is another R package that also implements Zipf.

It's also worth noting that the [Gnu Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) has an [implementation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/The-Pareto-Distribution.html) of the [Pareto distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) which is effectively the continuous analogue of the discrete Zipf distribution.

Also, the [Zeta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_distribution) is equivalent to Zipf for infinite *N*. The GSL has an [implementation](http://linux.duke.edu/~mstenner/free-docs/gsl-ref-1.1/gsl-ref_7.html#SEC141) of the [Riemann zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), so you could use that to construct the distribution yourself.

Comment: +1 for VGAM. Its `dzipf` function will give you a list of probabilities for each rank, which you can use to generate item accesses.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a Python Zipf-like distribution generator for `n` items with parameter `alpha >= 0`:

```
import random 
import bisect 
import math 

class ZipfGenerator: 

    def __init__(self, n, alpha): 
        # Calculate Zeta values from 1 to n: 
        tmp = [1. / (math.pow(float(i), alpha)) for i in range(1, n+1)] 
        zeta = reduce(lambda sums, x: sums + [sums[-1] + x], tmp, [0]) 

        # Store the translation map: 
        self.distMap = [x / zeta[-1] for x in zeta] 

    def next(self): 
        # Take a uniform 0-1 pseudo-random value: 
        u = random.random()  

        # Translate the Zipf variable: 
        return bisect.bisect(self.distMap, u) - 1
```

Comment: Excellent answer. For Python 3.x, add "from functools import *"

Comment: Or perhaps, `from functools import reduce`

Comment: self.distMap = [math.pow(float(x), alpha) / zeta[-1] for x in zeta]

Answer (score 10):

[numpy.random.zipf](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.zipf.html) generates Zipf samples using python.

Comment: Unfortunately, it uses Riemann's zeta function, so it only takes exponents higher than 1, while many P2P populations are best modeled with exponents lower than 1.

Answer (score 4):

A very efficient algorithm to generate Zipf distributed random variates was recently developed for the next versions (>= 3.6) of the Apache Commons Math library (see code [here](https://github.com/apache/commons-math/blob/138f84bfa5d36c8f6e2825640af1ed82daa9dc1d/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math4/distribution/ZipfDistribution.java)). It makes use of rejection-inversion sampling and also works for exponents less than 1. It does not require precalculating the CDF and keeping it in memory. Furthermore, the costs for generating one sample are constant and do not increase with the number of items.

Answer (score 0):

We were discussing the answer of @stanga in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31027739/3310838). There are some nice optimizations suggested for his algorithm.

Comment: Currently this barely passes for an answer.  You should include your solution here, don't just refer to it.